# Could not install from "@mui\material\generateUtilityClass" as it does not contain a package.json file

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dependencies, package.json

I am unable to install @mui\material\generateUtilityClass library for my React application.

On running `npm install @mui\material\generateUtilityClass`, I am receiving the following error:

Could not install from "@mui\material\generateUtilityClass" as it does not contain a package.json file.

On running `yarn add @mui\material\generateUtilityClass`, receiving the following error:

An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@mui%2fmaterial/generateUtilityClass: Request "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@mui%2fmaterial/generateUtilityClass" returned a 405"

Comment: You need to install @mui\material

Answer (score 1):

The following libraries need to be installed: @mui/lab and @mui/material

```
yarn add @mui/lab @mui/material
```

More: https://mui.com/material-ui/about-the-lab/